# nopcommerce 3.50 - Error "The controller for path '/Admin/Widget/ConfigureWidget' was not found or does not implement IController"

Tags: widget, runtime-error, nopcommerce

I've create a custom widget for nopcommerce 3.50 and tested it in my local envinronment and all works fine.

I've installed it on my production server but when I try to configure it, nopcommerce throw the exception:

```
The controller for path '/Admin/Widget/ConfigureWidget' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

All controllers are set as public and all classes have the same namespace root `"Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Mywidget"`.

Locally I've installed and configured it and it works fine

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I resolved.
It seems a known issue about cache or something else.

here a thread about this issue
http://www.nop-templates.com/boards/topic/404/bugs

Just recompile Nop.Web and upload the new nop.web.dll